# Why can't I get a development server up an running on my device using expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I want to try out some NFC action on iOS using React Native and Expo.
I’m following the getting started guide set out here [Create a development build - Expo Documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/create-a-build/) and I’ve managed to create a build and get it on my device.
The problem is getting access to my development server. According to the video I should be able to log in to my account (timestamp in video: 16:10) to view the dev servers.

Here’s the issue: I click log in → which brings me to the expo.dev site to log in. I enter my username and password which it seems to take, but after authenticating I get the message “Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid”.

From there on, I get the same message whenever I click on "Log In" on the account page in the app. Clearing history and Website data makes it possible to get back to the expo.dev login screen but I still have the same issue.

I’m on a managed workflow.
I’m running eas-cli/4.1.2 darwin-arm64 node-v18.15.0

Would love any help!